# Can I use DeferredResult with spring-ws?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-ws

Is there a way to perform proper asynchronous request processing with spring-ws?

The 'normal' Spring way of doing this (i.e. returning a Callable or DeferredResult from your controller action) doesn't work with spring-ws.

Specifically, spring-ws throws a SoapMessageDispatcher exception with the message

```
No adapter for endpoint [public org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResult<org.w3c.dom.Element>
```

(when T is an org.w3c.dom.Element)

If DeferredResult/Callable are not options with spring-ws then what options do I have?

Comment: Do you use `MessageDispatcherServlet`? Have you tried to wiring up Spring-WS in a `DispatcherServlet` http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/server.html#d4e950